# Hand the json file to list in python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have the JSON file :

```
{
  "relationships":
  [
    {
      "predicate": "wears", 
      "object": {"name": "sneakers", "h": 26, "w": 52, "y": 489, "x": 243, "id": 38207}, 
      "id": 15928, 
      "subject": {"name": "man", "h": 262, "w": 60, "y": 249, "x": 238, "id": 38206}
    }
  ],
  "id" = 1
},

{"relationships": 
  [
    {
      "predicate": "on", 
      "object": {"name": "street", "h": 262, "w": 714, "y": 328, "x": 77, "id": 38204}, 
      "id": 15927, 
      "subject": {"name": "shade", "h": 192, "w": 274, "y": 338, "x": 119, "id": 38205}
    }
  ],
  "id" = 1
}
```

How to extract the all "object name" and "id" as a list or output in two columns?

Comment: `"id" = 1` is not valid JSON.

Comment: It's also not valid JSON because the two outer objects aren't enclosed in square brackets.